# Number of Events in EventList

Tags: blackberry, java-me, calendar, enumeration

I need to find the number of Events stored in EventList from the events extracted from the calendar.

There was no `size()` method found.

Below is the code

```
EventList eventList = (EventList)PIM.getInstance().openPIMList(
        PIM.EVENT_LIST, PIM.READ_WRITE);
Enumeration eventsList = eventList.items(EventList.STARTING, startDateEvent, endDateEvent, false);
```

How can I find the number of events in the eventsList Enumeration?

Comment: And, just to make sure, you want the number of items in the list from your start date to end date, **not** the number of items in the whole `eventList`?

Comment: @Nate: Does my acceptance of your answer ... confirms it ... now lemme know abt this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, if you just want the number of events between your start and end dates, you'll need to count them.  `Enumeration` doesn't provide any interface for getting the number of elements.

```
 EventList eventList = (EventList)PIM.getInstance().openPIMList(
       PIM.EVENT_LIST, PIM.READ_WRITE);
 Enumeration eventsList = eventList.items(EventList.STARTING, startDateEvent, endDateEvent, false);
 int numEvents = 0;
 while (eventsList.hasMoreElements()) {
    eventsList.nextElement();
    numEvents++;
 }
 System.out.println("There are " + numEvents + " events in the list");
```

If you still want to iterate over the list **after** this counting, you'll need to get a new `Enumeration` object by calling `eventList.items()` again.

If, however, you want the number of events in the entire `eventList`, then you can get the size by casting your full list to a `BlackBerryEventList`:

From [the BlackBerry API docs](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/javax/microedition/pim/EventList.html):

> Any instance of EventList that is retrieved from PIM.openPIMList()
>   when specified pimListType==PIM.EVENT_LIST will be an instance of
>   BlackBerryEventList and can be successfully casted to
>   BlackBerryEventList, if desired, in order to use the RIM extension
>   functionality.

So, what you should do is cast your list to a `BlackBerryEventList` (or a `BlackBerryPIMList`), and then you can do this:

```
EventList eventList = (EventList)PIM.getInstance().openPIMList(
            PIM.EVENT_LIST, PIM.READ_WRITE);

if (eventList instanceof BlackBerryEventList) {  // should always succeed
    BlackBerryEventList bbEventList = (BlackBerryEventList)eventList;
    int sizeOfList = bbEventList.size();
}
```